# sed replace urls in file and re-save

Tags: regex, sed, terminal

been trying to use see for hours. Can get it working with normal strings but not urls with slashes.

trying to replace /var/www/vhosts/sandbox.modernactivity.co.uk/ to nothing.

```
sed 's%var%%' /Volumes/WEB_BACKUP/backups/ukfast/scripts/INCLUDE_list.txt
```

spits out //www/vhosts/sandbox.modernactivity.co.uk/restofurl/ and the original was /var/www/vhosts/sandbox.modernactivity.co.uk/restofurl/. Just can't get it to recognise the slashes.

It also doesn't seem to be updating the file?

any tips welcome!

Comment: this gets asked here every week. Good luck searching for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
sed 's#/var.*\.co\.uk/##' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "foo/foo/var/www/vhosts/sandbox.modernactivity.co.uk/bar/bar"|sed 's#/var.*\.co\.uk/##'
foo/foobar/bar
```

if you want to change the original file with sed, add -i option. like:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/' file
```

Comment: yeh though i only wanted the removed so sed 's#/var/www/vhosts/##' works now. Thanks! When i i use -i i get an error so don't seem to be able to use the same file. However old.txt >new.txt puts the results in a new file. Thanks for you your help? What are the definitions of % or #? think that's whats been confusing me...

Comment: -i means (changes) in-place backup is optional. it should work. check man page of sed. # is for 's' command 's/../../' could be s#..#..# . since your text has "/(slash)" I don't want to escape every slash.

Comment: ah - sorry. This doesn't seem to work with a variable?DIR=/var/www/vhosts/, sed 's#$DIR##'. do i need to use a different separator?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find . -name "yourfile.txt" -print | xargs sed -i "" 's/\/var\/www\/.*\.co\.uk//g'
```

use \ to escape '/'

If you are working on Mac use `-i ""`

Else on Linux just write `-i`